# Different animate.css animations in IE10 and IE11

Tags: jquery, css, animation, css-animations, animate.css

I'm using the animate.css framework to animate some social media icons but I'm getting different animations in IE10 and IE11. Is there a specific prefix or other trick to fix that behavoir?

Here is my jQuery Code:

```
$('li.social-item').hover(
  function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('animated pulse');
});
```

Here are the corresponding CSS classes:

```
.animated {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

.pulse {
  -webkit-animation-name: pulse;
  animation-name: pulse;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  }

  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.05, 1.05, 1.05);
    transform: scale3d(1.05, 1.05, 1.05);
  }

  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: *What am I doing wrong?* - you want to get a debugging help without posting a fiddle

Comment: Tried your code in both versions, same animation: https://jsfiddle.net/nydjhLce/ .... so how does they differ when you try?

Comment: @smnbbrv ..how can I post a fiddle that simulates IE behavior???

Comment: @LGSon ..if I open the animation in IE 9,10 & 11 I get a slide up animation after a weird pulse animation

Comment: @Codehan25 if you cannot post the fiddle then you won't get the help...

Comment: I just tried it in IE 10,11 with no sliding, so please post a minimal code snippet that shows that sliding ....  and IE 9, which you didn't mention in the question, does not support `scale3d` and need the `-ms` prefix on transform

Comment: IE9 also doesn't support `animation`

Comment: @LGSon ..please check the social media icons at the bottom: http://codehan.de/contact

Comment: I did, in IE11 ... can see that some move a fraction sideways but they all zooms in and out nicely. Have you tried with `scale(1.05)` instead of `scale3d(...)`

Comment: @LGSon It does not work. I get either the mentioned slide-up animation or a broken pulse-animation (Also with IE11). Chrome, Firefox and Safari all work perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with `%transforms`. IE10 AND IE11 has problem with %transforms. So try blending from/to with px.

Comment: No, IE do not have a general problem with `transform`, but if you found it having that in this case, I suggest you show that, and a solution, with code.